# What's the difference between dnxcore50 on Windows and Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core

It looks like `System.Data.SqlClient` is defined in dnxcore50 when running on Windows, but not on Linux.

Aren't they both [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)?

For example, an app that targets dnxcore50 beta7, or beta8, and references `System.Data.SqlClient` will build and run fine in Windows, but on Linux will compile fine only to at execution throw this runtime error;

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET 5 RC1, `SqlClient` is now cross platform and so you can query Microsoft SQL Server from Linux and Mac too.

More info in the release notes below (look for **Cross-platform SQL Client**)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx

Comment: Whilst this infers why SQL client was previously unavailable on Linux/Mac it does not answer how dnxcore50 differs per platform. How was this working on Windows for beta7, beta8?  Was that same SQL Client library but only supporting windows, or, does dnxcore50 point to the existing libraries on Windows?

Comment: Yes, it was the same SQL client library that was supported only on Windows. When the framework is `dnxcore50`, you cannot use the installed assemblies on Windows, for example GAC which is what you are referring I think.